# Change Kinetic.Text's text on Group click event

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Just started checking out kinetic js. I have many groups, each of which has a `Kinetic.Text` and a `Kinetic.Rect`.

I can easily change any text by this prompt;

```
text.on('click', function(evt) {
          this.setText(prompt('New Text:'));
          layer.draw(); //redraw the layer containing the textfield
        });
```

But i want to change the rectangle's (which encompasses the text ) height and width according to the text. So, this is what I tried, but this doesn't work. It shows me the prompt but doesn't change the text and also my group becomes unclickable after that!;

```
 group.on('click', function(evt) {
              this.get('.textbox').setText(prompt('New Text:'));
              //this.get('.rectangle')....change rect's height/width here
              layer.draw(); //redraw the layer containing the textfield
            });
```

rectangle and textbox are the names for bothe `Kinteic.Text` and `Kinetic.Rect` in each group. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kinetic's getTextWidth() to see your text's width. Then adjust the rectangle.

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/MZCCA/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <button id="fitText">Fit text in the rectangle</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.0-beta2.js"></script>
    <script>

        $("#fitText").click(function(){ redraw();})

        function redraw(){
            var textWidth=text.getTextWidth();
            // redraw the container--add 10px because the text has 5px padding
            container.setWidth(textWidth+10);
            layer.draw();
        }

        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 400,
          height: 200
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        var container = new Kinetic.Rect({
          x: 100,
          y: 30,
          width: 75,
          height: 30,
          fill:"yellow",
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 4,
          draggable: true
        });

        var text = new Kinetic.Text({
          x: 100,
          y: 30,
          text: 'Here is some text.',
          fontSize: 18,
          fontFamily: 'Calibri',
          fill: '#555',
          padding: 5,
          align: 'center'
        });

        layer.add(container);
        layer.add(text);
        stage.add(layer);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```